# Является ли <center> костылем?

Tags: html

Почему никто его не использует?

Comment: Не костыль, но "deprecated". Проще говоря, не используйте, пока не наступит 1998г.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Использование этого тега осуждается спецификацией HTML, валидный код получается только при использовании переходного `<!DOCTYPE>`

http://htmlbook.ru/html/center

Проще говоря, устарел и в html5 не используется

Answer (score 3):

> Является ли  костылем?

Именно! И создавался он когда-то давно разработчиками именно как временный костыль.

Почему? - Потому что `html` - это всего лишь структура документа, а за все остальное (выравнивание, цвет, размеры, ...) должен отвечать `css`. Разделение семантики и презентации.

В html5 эту оплошность исправили и полностью исключили данный тег из использования.
[Полный список устаревших тегов.](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml5/ustarevshie-tegi-i-atributy)

Аналоги выравнивания с помощью `css`:

```
text-align: center;

margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 2):

Большинство тегов, которые отвечают за внешнее отображение на сайте, в стандарте HTML5 считаются устаревшими. К этим тегам относятся: `<center>, <big>, <font>` и т.п. В качестве исключений оставили теги `<b>, <i>`. Одна из причин - частое использования на сайте в визуальных редакторах и т.п.

Практически все устаревшие теги до сих пор работают (кроме `<blink>`). Однако эта ситуация может изменится со временем, поэтому не советуют использовать их

Comment: _"В качестве исключений оставили тег `<b>, <u>, <u>, <s>`."_ - неправда (и почему `u` два раза?). Насколько я помню, там так: `u` - выкинули, `b` и `i` - deprecated, `s` - приобрёл семантику, `strike` выкинули.

Comment: Qwertiy, поправил, а теперь мне бы доступ на источник, насчет тегов b и i